# Read the value of pointer to pointer array of struct passed to a function

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, struct

**Context:**
Recently I've started programming in a more professional way and currently I'm working on a C driver library that should look decent in code both functionally and esthetically so I've just started to use the consept of pointers more intensely and not very experienced with it in relation to how it works on code.

**Problem:**
Basically I'm trying to read a values inside each of the struct with a for loop inside initFunt()
My solution to that was to create a struct pointer group for all the created btn_params_t instants and pass that pointer group to initFunc() and from init access each struct member with something like "Btn Pin in the first struct is: %d", BtnPointer[0]->BtnPin

Here's basically the code to explain it:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>


typedef struct btn_params_t
{

    uint8_t BtnPin;
    uint8_t BtnActiveState;
    uint8_t BtnPinPullUp;
    uint8_t BtnPinPullDown;
    void (*PressedISR)();
    void (*ReleasedISR)();


} btn_params_t;

void initFunc(btn_params_t **BtnPointer){


  printf("Btn Pin in the first struct is: %d", BtnPointer[0]->BtnPin);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  btn_params_t Btn0Params = {
                .BtnPin = 4,
                .BtnActiveState = 0,
                .BtnPinPullUp =  1,
                .BtnPinPullDown = 0
                
  };
  
  btn_params_t Btn1Params = {.BtnPin = 32};


  btn_params_t** BtnGroup = {&Btn0Params, &Btn1Params};

  initFunc(BtnGroup);

}
```

How'd you do such a thing?

Comment: `btn_params_t **BtnGroup` ==> `btn_params_t *BtnGroup[]` ? Related, you're prolly gonna also want to pass a *magnitude* (e.g. how many) into that function.

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers when you pass them as function arguments. But that doesn't mean you can use an array to initialize a pointer.

Comment: Yes what you suggested to do fix seems to work, but isn't it possible to determine the amount of pointers *BtnGroup[] points to similar to the use of sizeof()

Comment: You should pass an extra argument that is the _count_ of the number of elements in the array

Comment: @CraigEstey no way to determine that with something like sizeof() of the array pointer to figure out how many elements it points to? that element count declaration seem cumbersome and unnecessary.

Comment: `main` defines `BtnGroup`, so it can do: `sizeof(BtnGroup) / sizeof(BtnGroup[0])` to get the count but `initFunc` can _not_ (doesn't work on _pointers_ to arrays). Because it's using pointers, you could do: `btn_params_t** BtnGroup = { &Btn0Params, &Btn1Params, NULL };`. Then, `initFunc` could check for `NULL`. In general, you have to pass the count (i.e. C does _not_ have arrays that automatically carry a length/count attribute like perl/python). You could do something similar with a struct: `typedef struct { size_t btn_count; size_t btn_capacity; btn_params_t *btn_list; } btn_list_t;`

Comment: OK but counting it in the initFunc seem quite in efficient as long as the pointer array is big enough as it takes as much clock cycles as the amount of pointer elements but I guess sizeof() works the same way just wondered wether the CPU/memory has some special function to count it with a single cycle, anyways that answer is sufficient for the current application so thanks.